# Mapping function by groups in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The same regression model has been estimated on several groups using `dplyr::group_by()` and `broom::tidy()`. The estimates should be used to plot the regression function for each group in ggplot.

The following code works for base `r` `curve()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_tbl <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Col_1, ~Col_2, ~Col_3,
      "A",     "(Intercept)",     30,
      "A",     "x",               10,
      "A",     "x2",              -2,
      "B",     "(Intercept)",     40,
      "B",     "x",               20,
      "B",     "x2",              -1
  )

my_tbl %>%
  split(.$Col_1) %>%
  map( ~curve(.$Col_3[1] + .$Col_3[2] * x + .$Col_3[3] * x^2, 
              1, 
              30, 
              main = paste(.$Col_1[1]), 
              ylab = "y"))
```

The `stat_function()` is not able to find the parameter values in `my_tbl`.

```
my_tbl %>% 
  nest(-Col_1) %>% 
  mutate(plot = map(data, ~ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(1, 30)), 
                                  mapping = aes(x = x)) + 
                             stat_function()))
```

Comment: I see no base R in either code block. Also, can you explain what each block attempts to accomplish? Both appear to plot. You do not assign those piped statements to objects.

Comment: The function to plot is: 20+10*x-2*x^2 for group A, 40+20*x-1*x^2 for B, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you went with `nest` instead of `split` (as per the base R approach)? Because that works fine with `ggplot`, and the `map` logic matches that of the base R solution.

With `nest`, since the `Col_1` column isn't part of the nested data, I used `map2` instead of `map` in order to pass both `data` & `Col_1` to `ggplot`.

```
result1 <- my_tbl %>%
  split(.$Col_1) %>%
  map(~ ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(0, 30)), aes(x)) +
        ggtitle(.$Col_1[1]) +
        stat_function(fun = function(x) .x$Col_3[1] + .x$Col_3[2] * x + .x$Col_3[3] * x^2))

result2 <- my_tbl %>%
  nest(-Col_1) %>%
  mutate(plot = map2(data, Col_1,
                     ~ ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(0, 30)), aes(x)) +
                       ggtitle(.y) +
                       stat_function(fun = function(x) .x$Col_3[1] + .x$Col_3[2] * x + .x$Col_3[3] * x^2)))

# resulting plots are the same
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = result1)
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = result2$plot)
```

[image: plot]